# Uploading Sound Blob on Server Using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.3, recordrtc

Friends, Im following [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-PHP) to capture audio on my website, and successfully managed to upload Recorded file on PHP server via XMLHTTPRequest. Im uploading here my Code:

```js
 var audio_context;
  var recorder;
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var fileType = 'audio';
  var fileName = 'ABCDEF.wav';

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.');
 console.log('Media stream created.');

    // Uncomment if you want the audio to feedback directly
    //input.connect(audio_context.destination);
    //__log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input);
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
 console.log('Recorder Initialized');
  }

  function startRecording(button) 
  {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
 console.log('Recording....');
  }

  function stopRecording(button) 
  {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Stopped recording.');
 console.log('Stopped Recording');
 

    // create WAV download slink using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();
    recorder.clear();    

  }


  function createDownloadLink()
  {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob)
 {
  var counter = 0;
  
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      
  var fileName = 'Recording'+counter+'.wav';
  
  var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName, {
                            type: 'audio/wav'
                        });
      
  var formData = new FormData();

                        // recorded data
  formData.append('audio-blob', fileObject);

                        // file name
        formData.append('audio-filename', fileObject.name);
  
  
  $.ajax({
                            url: 'save.php', // replace with your own server URL
                            data: formData,
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(response) {
                                if (response === 'success') {
                                    alert('successfully uploaded recorded blob');
         console.log('Successfully Uploaded Recorded Blob');
                                    // file path on server
                                    var fileDownloadURL = '/uploads/' + fileObject.name;

                                
        } else 
        {
                                    alert(response); // error/failure
                                }
                            }
                        });

    });

  }


  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;
      __log('Audio context set up.');
      __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
  };
```

```html
 <button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>
```

and this is my Save.php file:

```html
<?php
// upload directory
$filePath = 'uploads/' . $_POST['audio-filename'];

// path to ~/tmp directory
$tempName = $_FILES['audio-blob']['tmp_name'];

// move file from ~/tmp to "uploads" directory
if (!move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath)) {
    // failure report
    echo 'Problem saving file: '.$tempName;
    die();
}

// success report
echo 'success';
?>
```

Now i have to apply this mechanism in my Laravel project,Im new on Laravel Framework and have no clue how can i make it happen. Kindly help me to find a solution.
Regards

Comment: Have you read the documentation on uploaded files and how to store them?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: yes, i read that. problem is here im dealing with a blob that i captured using getusermedia()... problem is to upload in a directory.

Answer (score 2):

The following scripts used in the view file take mic input and create the blob:

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>

<script>
function captureMicrophone(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(callback).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Unable to access your microphone.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

var recorder;

//on click of a button representing microphone
$('#inputFields').on('click','*[class*=microphoneBtn]',function(){
    var audio = $('$audio'); //this refers to an HTML audio element
    var button = this;

    if(recorder == null || recorder.state === 'stopped'){ //start recording
        captureMicrophone(function(microphone) {
            setSrcObject(microphone, audio);
            audio.muted = true;
            audio.play();

            recorder = RecordRTC(microphone, {
                type: 'audio',
                recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
                desiredSampRate: 16000
            });
        recorder.startRecording();
        recorder.microphone = microphone;
    }else{ //stop recording
        recorder.stopRecording(function(){
            var blob = this.getBlob();  //get actual blob file
            audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //set src of audio element    
            audio.muted = false;
            audio.play();
            recorder.microphone.stop();
        });
    }    

});
</script>


//on click of the save button, save the audio file to server
$('#inputFields').on('click','*[class*=saveBtn]',function(){
    var blob = recorder.getBlob();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('audio-blob', blob);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: //your url,
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //success message           
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            //error message 
        }                              
    });

});
@endsection
```

Thus, you will be able to store the actual wav file using the following code in your Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $blobInput = $request->file('audio-blob');

    //save the wav file to 'storage/app/audio' path with fileanme test.wav
    Storage::put('audio/test.wav', file_get_contents($blobInput));
}
```

Comment: have u ever implemented this mechanism by urself ? if yes then please share some demo with me !

Comment: I've implemented it in a project I'm currently working on, but unfortunately I don't have a live demo to offer yet. If you require any additional info on the code, do let me know.

Comment: yes it would be a great pleasure if u show me that file in which u used that code, thanks

Comment: yes it would be a great pleasure if u show me that file in which u used that code, thanks

Comment: please, find in my answer a more detailed version of the code I used...